# How to define an f(x) function from a list in python

Tags: python

I would appreciate help on this.
I have a list of the form `[-100,20,30,40,50]`.

I need to create a function of the form `-100+20x+30x**2+40x**3+50x**5`.

I understand that some kind of a for-loop is needed in order to make the transformation, such as:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lambda x: sum(lst[i]*x**i)
```

output is as follows:

```
<function irr_newton.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fb98844ad30>
```

Comment: Did you try running your code? Did you get the output you require? Please update your question with sample given inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Do you want to create a function, a string, or do you want to output said string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There numerous ways to do this. But if you want to use lambda, this is one way to do it.

```
coefs = [-100,20,30,40,50]
function = lambda x: sum([coef*x**i for i, coef in enumerate(coefs)])
```

Test:

```
function(2)
```

Output:

```
1180
```

Alternatively, you can go about it using a for loop:

```
def function(x):
    coefs = [-100,20,30,40,50]
    
    result = 0
    for i, num in enumerate(coefs):
        result += num*x**i
        
    return result
```

I thought of one more solution, where you use a recursive function.

```
coefs = [-100,20,30,40,50]
def function(x):
    if coefs == []:
        return 0
    
    result = coefs.pop(-1)*x**(len(coefs))
    
    return function(x) + result
```

Comment: Lambda is all I am familliar of, could you please show a way without it?

Comment: I can only think of for loop and while loop alternatives. I've edited the post to include them.

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel for your answer.  When you have a for loop where you need both the element and its index it is considered more Pythonic to use `enumerate` instead of `range(len(... ))`.

Comment: Alright noted. Thanks. I'll edit the post to apply the change

Comment: @ShoshanBen-Tzvi I added another solution, where you use a recursive function to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
def polynomial(coefficients):
    return lambda x: sum(coef * x ** i for i, coef in enumerate(coefficients))
```

```
>>> p = polynomial([1, 0, 1])
>>> p(1)
2
```

Lambda functions are just like any other functions so this is equivalent

```
def polynomial(coefficients):
    def inner(x):
        return sum(coef * x ** i for i, coef in enumerate(coefficients))
    return inner
```

Comment: only maybe it shouldn't be a starred argument because they would likely pass the list (unpacked)

Comment: I get an error when I run your code.

Comment: @quamrana never say that, how does it help to say "not working" ? Always give at least the exception message, and better the stacktrace

Comment: @azro: Its neither my answer nor my question. I expected the poster to have tried their code and also received the error. Oh, you mean I should edit their answer to include the stacktrace that I see?

Comment: `f = lambda x, coefficients: sum(coef * x ** i for i, coef in enumerate(coefficients))`

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary: That misses the point of defining a function to return a lambda.

Comment: @quamrana Right. so `f = lambda coefficients: lambda x: sum(coef * x ** i for i, coef in enumerate(coefficients))`. It can then called like `f([-100, 20, 30, 40, 50])(2)`

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary: Ok, that's an interesting approach. I hadn't thought of that. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I was on mobile,  now the function takes a list as an argument. The code runs and I've added a usage example.

Comment: @quamrana just telling that "I got error" is useless. At least say "I have an XXX error"